# How can I avoid that my logged-in user goes back to the login url in angular 16?

Tags: angular, authentication, reroute

I have an angular 16 application and want to avoid that a user that is logged in can return to the login url. It should be possible with an authGuard, but I don't know how I could achieve this.
In my app-routing module, I have this:

```
import { authGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';
import { LoginComponent } from './user/login/login.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './user/profile/profile.component';
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/user/profile', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'user',
    children: [
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [authGuard] },

      { path: '', redirectTo: 'profile', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'profile', pathMatch: 'full' },
    ],
  },

  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/user/profile', pathMatch: 'full' }
]
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

and my authGuard looks like this:

```
import { CanActivateFn, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../user/auth.service';
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

export const authGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
  const jwtHelper: JwtHelperService = inject(JwtHelperService);
  const authService = inject(AuthService);
  if (token && !jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    authService.logout();
    return false;
  }
};
```

The token authentication works fine, and the user/profile url is properly protected by the authGuard. For user/login however, this does not make sense, since everyone should be able to go to this page.

I tried to put the authGuard at the end of the user path, so it all parent and children paths are guarded, but that causes issues with finding the correct path. I also tried to check in the authGurad `if (state.url == '/user/login') {router.navigate(['/user/profile']}` but this causes a circular reroute.

Comment: If the token is not null and it is not expired then use the `Router` to route him to the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution that I came up with a while ago. The paths that should be accessed only after logging in are wrapped in an empty path (notice there is no `pathMatch` property so it is by default `pathMatch: prefix`, basically making it act like a wildcard path. This empty path has a `canMatch` guard which checks whether the user is logged in.

The beauty of this solution is that even if the user enters `/user/login` in the address bar while logged in, the empty path (and its children) will always be matched so they will not be able to go to the login page.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-9ft6pf?file=src%2Flogin.component.ts)

```
{
  path: 'user',
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      children: [
        { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
        { path: '**', redirectTo: 'profile' }
      ],
      canMatch: [authGuard]
    },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This solutions seems to prevent going to /user/login once logged in, but when you are not logged in, it doesn't render the LoginComponent when going to /user/login, and doesn't do anything when having a blank url (which should redirect to either /user/login or user/profile, depending on login status)

Comment: Not sure why that would be since the two wildcard paths should take care of those cases. Added a stackblitz example of the routes in action in the original comment.